# Output Of Wreath product in GAP

Tags: gap

The output of WreathProduct of two permutation groups in GAP is a permutation group, I want to compute the wreath product of two general linear groups.

```
l:=group of 3x3 matrices of size 6 over GF(2)
g:=GL(2,2)
gap> WreathProduct(PSL(2,2),l);
<group of size 279936 with 4 generators>
gap> GeneratorsOfGroup(last);
[ WreathProductElement((2,3),(),(),(),(),(),()), 
  WreathProductElement((1,2),(),(),(),(),    (),()), 
  WreathProductElement((),(),(),(),(),(),(1,2)(3,5)(4,6)), 
  WreathProductElement((),(),(),(),(),(),(1,3)(2,4)(5,6)) ]
```

how will the "WreathProductElements" of generator be considered as matrix group?

Comment: What do you mean by matrix form? You mean realize the group as a group of matrices? Over what field?

Comment: So is that a yes? You need a representation as a group of matrices? It still does not answer over what field.

Comment: No, I don't mean something. I am asking what you mean by matrix form.

Comment: Then ask GAP whether they are isomorphic? GAP should be able to answer this for you.

Comment: It's a good practice to put a fragment of the GAP session to show what have you tried. It may help to answer, since the person who answers would not need to construct an example from scratch.

Comment: If you are trying to understand a paper or result, you might also want to mention that result. I suspect you are not asking GAP the right question.

Comment: In this edited version there no longer seems to be any question.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are asking the wrong question. What are you actually trying to understand?

Comment: Thanks for some GAP code. That's still not a complete example though, since you do not provide GAP code to construct `l`. BTW, `g` is not used in what follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the Kronecker product.

Is this the group you want?

```
gap> l := Group( [
>   [[1,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,0,1]],
>   [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,1]]
> ] * One(GF(2)) );;
gap> g := GL(2,2);;
gap> gw := List( GeneratorsOfGroup( g ), x -> KroneckerProduct( x, One(l) ) );;
gap> lw := List( GeneratorsOfGroup( l ), x -> KroneckerProduct( One(g), x ) );;
gap> w := Group( Concatenation( gw, lw ) );;
gap> Size(w);
36
gap> Perform( GeneratorsOfGroup(w), function(x) Display(x); Print("\n"); end );
 1 . . 1 . .    . . . 1 . .    1 . . . . .    1 . . . . .
 . 1 . . 1 .    . . . . 1 .    . 1 1 . . .    . 1 . . . .
 . . 1 . . 1    . . . . . 1    . . 1 . . .    . 1 1 . . .
 . . . 1 . .    1 . . . . .    . . . 1 . .    . . . 1 . .
 . . . . 1 .    . 1 . . . .    . . . . 1 1    . . . . 1 .
 . . . . . 1    . . 1 . . .    . . . . . 1    . . . . 1 1
```

This is all matrices of the form: $$w = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\\ C & D \end{bmatrix} : A,B,C,D \in \ell \right\}$$

If you swap the order of the arguments to `KroneckerProduct` then you get:
$$v = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & B \\ 0 & C & D \end{bmatrix} : A,B,C,D \in g, I = 1_g \right\}$$

Here `g` is all $2\times 2$ matrices, $$g = \operatorname{GL}(2,2) = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} : A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right\} $$ and `l` is the unique (up to iso) 3-dimensional rep of $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)$, $l=\operatorname{SL}(1,2) \times \operatorname{GL}(2,2)= \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & B \\ 0 & C & D \end{bmatrix} : A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, I=1 \right\}$.

Comment: Concatenation has no special role. This is equivalent: `w := Group( gw[1], gw[2], lw[1], lw[2] );`

Comment: If I want to compute the product of l and GL(2,2), then the result changes?